# Error while connecting HC-05 bluetooth module with python via bluetooth

Tags: python, sockets, bluetooth, communication, rfcomm

I have been trying to connect my `hc 05 bt` module with my laptop and to achieve a communication with `Idle`.

At first i connected my bt device manually from laptop's bluetooth settings and then I was able to get the module's `bt address` by using the following code:

```
import bluetooth

target_name = "HC-05"
target_address = None

nearby_devices = bluetooth.discover_devices()

for bdaddr in nearby_devices:
 if target_name == bluetooth.lookup_name( bdaddr ):
    target_address = bdaddr
    break

if target_address is not None:
  print "found target bluetooth device with address ", target_address
else:
  print "could not find target bluetooth device nearby"
```

I received the bluetooth address as `"98:D3:31:70:7D:2D"`

Now i wrote the following code to connect `HC-05` via python..

```
bd_addr = "98:D3:31:70:7D:2D"

port = 20
sock=bluetooth.BluetoothSocket( bluetooth.RFCOMM )
sock.connect((bd_addr, port))
sock.send("1")

sock.close()
```

Now i browse through my laptop's bluetooth comm port settings and found 2 things
1st...

```
COM19 
Direction--- Incoming... 
Name--- HC-05
```

2nd...

```
COM20
Direction--- Outgoing

...
Name--- HC-05 'Dev B'
```

Hence I chose `COM20` as I want to transmit data from Python.

When I run this code i get error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\TestBluetooth.py", line 26, in <module>
    sock.connect((bd_addr, port))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bluetooth\msbt.py", line 72, in connect
    bt.connect (self._sockfd, addr, port)
IOError: A socket operation failed because the destination host was down.
```

I tried both `COM19` and `COM20` but got the same error.
My Bluetooth is connected via `TX` pin to `arduino's RX pin` and the arduino is connected to my PC so there is no error of `COM port` sharing that occurs sometimes.

Also when I connect my bluetooth module with laptop bluetooth and open `Bluetooth Serial terminal` and transmit data from there it works fine.
So there's some problem in my understanding and writing of Python code.
Please help...

Comment: "Hence i chose COM20". That's not correct for the `port` number. It needs to be the rfcomm port that the other end is listening on.

Comment: So how can i get to know what is the rfcomm port ? What changes should i make in the code>?

Comment: What are you trying to connect to exactly? At least one end needs to be listening on an rfcomm port. How you find that port depends on your system. If you wrote both apps then you should know what the port is as you would have chosen it. If you did not write the peer app then you need to use SDP (Service Discovery Protocol) or find the port some other way (e.g. read the source code).

Comment: I'm connecting my laptop to hc05 which is on an arduino... With the bluetooth serial terminal application i'm able to send data and receive it on my arduino serial mionitor... But the same thing is not happening when i wrote the following code on python..I'm new to python and don't know how to properly use pybluez that's why facing this problem..